# Creating a collection of base class, then access properties of derived classes in the collection items

Tags: c#, collections, liskov-substitution-principle

I have classes like this,

```
class Base
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    string DerivedProperty1 { get; set; }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    string DerivedProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a collection class like this

```
public class MyCollection    
{
    List<Base> items;

    public void Add(Base baseItem)
    {
         // if baseItem is Derived1, if items contain an item of type Derived1 and has the same DerivedProperty1 value as baseItem, throw exception
         // if baseItem is Derived2, if items contain an item of type Derived2 and has the same DerivedProperty2 value as baseItem, throw exception
         items.Add(baseItem);
    }
}
```

I don't think that checking type of baseItem then casting is a very good practice, is it? Otherwise how do you suggest I solve this design problem?

Comment: The question is: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this construct? Why are you checking for these properties and throwing Exceptions?

Comment: The reason is input validation, as is written in the comment in the code, if "baseItem" is of type Dervied1 and its DerivedProperty1 equals certain value, and "items" field of the collection already has an item of type Derived1 that has its DerivedProperty1 equals to the exact value of     that of  "baseItem", then this should be regarded as a duplicate and an exception is thrown to notify the user that this is a duplicate. and same is done for Derived2 type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code and comments, the correct approach would be to give `Base` a `IsDuplicateOf` method and override this in the derived classes. Something like this:

```
class Base
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDuplicateOf(Base other)
    {
        return other != null && Id == other.Id;
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    string DerivedProperty1 { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDuplicateOf(Base other)
    {
        return IsDuplicateOf(other as Derived1);
    }

    private bool IsDuplicateOf(Derived1 other)
    {
        return other != null && DerivedProperty1 == other.DerivedProperty1;
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    string DerivedProperty2 { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDuplicateOf(Base other)
    {
        return IsDuplicateOf(other as Derived2);
    }

    private bool IsDuplicateOf(Derived2 other)
    {
        return other != null && DerivedProperty2 == other.DerivedProperty2;
    }
}
```

And you would use that method in your `Add` method:

```
public void Add(Base baseItem)
{
     if(items.Any(x => baseItem.IsDuplicateOf(x)))
         throw new DuplicateItemException(...);

     items.Add(baseItem);
}
```

Please note however, that this approach might become slow if there are many items in the list and the code inside `IsDuplicateOf` gets more complex.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better solution then what I suggested, though I don't quite get why you are overloading the IsDuplicateOf method - seems to me you could just have the logic all wrapped up inside the public method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, I could have it all in one method, but then I would need to come up with another name for the `other` that is casted to the derived class. And I am lazy when it comes to names, so I just overload. A similar pattern is used when you override `Equals` and also implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth but why did you make two overloads for the IsDuplicateOf method anyways, isn't it possible to do all the work (cast and compare) directly within the overriding IsDuplicateOf ?

Comment: @Sisyphus: Yes, it is possible, but I don't like the code that this would create. You are free to implement everything in the public method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access derived class properties from base class without casting to the derived class first. However, in your case, you can do something different - instead of your current `Add` method, that takes a `Base` instance as a parameter, create a couple of `Add` method overloads, one for each derived class:

```
public void Add(Derived1 item)
{
    if(items.OfType<Derived1>().Any(i => i.DerivedProperty1 == item.DerivedProperty1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("An item with the same DerivedProperty1 already exist"); 
     items.Add(baseItem);
}

public void Add(Derived2 item)
{
    if(items.OfType<Derived2>().Any(i => i.DerivedProperty2 == item.DerivedProperty2)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("An item with the same DerivedProperty2 already exist"); 
     items.Add(baseItem);
}
```